# HQL Expects java.time.duration even though method-head and usage suggest LocalDateTime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am writing a query within a JpaRepository which takes a String and 3 LocalDateTimes as parameters. Within the query I first compare the String like an Id and afterwards I use a different Column of the corresponding Entity to create LocalDateTimes using appropriate operators for Hibernate 6.

The Application starts up normal but when i call the query I get the following Error:

```
Argument [2023-01-23T11:43:59] of type [java.time.LocalDateTime] did not match parameter type [java.time.Duration (n/a)]
```

The Argument obviously got parsed correctly by the Restcontroller but Hibernate does not seem to create the query as expected.

The following is the Code for the Repository and the query in question:

```
public interface ExchangePairRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

@Query("SELECT ep.unit FROM MyEntity ep WHERE ep.id= :id AND ((ep.context = 'start' AND ((ep.unit = 'day' AND (:start+ ep.duration day) > :now) "
        + "OR (ep.unit = 'month' AND (:start+ ep.duration month) > :now))) OR (ep.context = 'end' AND ((ep.unit = 'day' AND (:now + ep.duration day) > :end) "
        + "OR (ep.unit = 'month' AND (:now + ep.duration month) > :end)) ))")
List<String> findViable(@Param("matNrOrig") String id, @Param("start") LocalDateTime start, @Param("end") LocalDateTime end,
        @Param("now") LocalDateTime now);
```

}

Below is the Entity which i being used for the query:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
@Data
public class MyEntity{
    (...)

@Column(name = "id_orig")
private String idOrig;

´
@Column(name = "id_target")
private String idTarget;

@Column(name = "context")
private String context;

@Column(name = "duration")
private int duration;

@Column(name = "unit")
private String unit;
```

}

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

I am using Hibernate 6.1.6.Final and Spring Boot 3.0.1 with Java 17

Edit:

Casting the parameters within the query solved the problem for now, though it does not look very pretty. I will just wait for the bug being fixed in one of the next releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the new parameter type inference logic. I can reproduce with just this query:

```
session.createQuery("select :dt + 1 day")
        .setParameter("dt", LocalDateTime.now())
        .getSingleResult();
```

I have opened an issue for you here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16102

**UPDATE**

The following workaround is very ugly, but works:

```
session.createQuery("select cast(:dt as LocalDateTime) + 1 day")
        .setParameter("dt", LocalDateTime.now())
        .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much. Is there a workaround for now? I guess i will keep wating for a new release and do the calculation in java for now.

Comment: Now that you ask, I just thought of one. (Updated the answer.)